# If Casimir vacuum has negative energy, why it is attractive, and not repulsive?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, dark-energy, cosmological-constant, casimir-effect

I heard that negative energy should be repulsive. Why Casimir vacuum is attractive then?
Can we explain it by saying Casimir vacuum is electromagnetically attractive but gravitationally repulsive?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/637274/2451

Comment: Casimir effect (in theory) is purely electromagnetic, gravity plays no role. It can be both attractive and repulsive, depending on geometry of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

The Casimir force can be both attractive or repulsive.

The repulsive force has been experimentally measured, see [Measured long-range repulsive Casimir–Lifshitz forces](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4169270/) or [Chiral Casimir Forces: Repulsive, Enhanced, Tunable](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.07994)
.

Wikipedia is also good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect#Repulsive_forces

Answer (score 0):

*Why is Casimir vacuum energy attractive:* The vacuum energy (zero point fluctuations) of the electromagnetic field would create a pair of virtual photons in between the perfectly conducting plates. There are modes of virtual photons on the other side of the plate which are slightly suppressed by the modes in between the plates. Hence the force appears to be attractive as the modes outside the gap push the plates towards each other.

The loop diagrams, representing the vacuum energy give infinite energy, which after application of a cutoff can be made finite but still large. This should be have been detected already but, we see that, it is at least 54 orders smaller. This is the Cosmological Constant problem. The very existence of such a significant amount of negative energy implies vioaltion of Weak Equivalence Principle. Hence many experiments have been proposed to measured this effect.