# If gravitational potential energy is negative, why does not it produce any repelling force?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity, potential-energy, dark-energy

The gravitational potential energy is usually considered negative. There is even zero-energy universe theory.
If so, why it does not produce any repelling force? Or does it in form of cosmological constant, etc?

Answer (score 2):

You should not consider the sign of the potential for a simple reason: energy and potential are always defined up to an arbitrary constant shift. What is meaningful is the energy difference for example. Or derivative of the potential (which is proportional to the force).

$F = - \nabla V$

Gravitational potential is generally considered as negative to emphasize that a system in a gravitational potential is bounded. In other words the system will always be attracted by the massive object which generates the gravitational field, except at infinity where the potential is usually set to 0.

This is not related to GR, dark energy or whatever.

Comment: Potential enerty at infinity is zero, this provides good absolute measure. Anyway, whether it is positive or negative, a ong as it decreases, some ind of repulsion should arise or attraction decrease.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_energy

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-energy_universe

Comment: no it does not, pull an elastic band it is gaining an elastic potential and it is wanting to attract it back together when it pulls back together it loses that elastic potential, so that energy loss is still an attraction, so you cannot state that a loss in energy will always be repulsion it matters how the energy is applied by a force to cause an outcome.

Comment: @Anixx the potential energy at infinity equalling zero is *not* an absolute measure, it is a convention. The value can be shifted by any arbitrary constant without affecting the physics, as Quarroz mentioned.

Comment: This is wrong, “-1”. OP clearly asks about GR where the actual value of energy matters because of the gravitational field this energy creates. Incidentally, this does not contradict gauge freedom for potentials. While self-energy of gravitational field is a complicated subject one could think about electrostatics: energy density is proportional to square of gradient (i.e. change per unit length) of potential,  $\rho\sim (\nabla\phi)^2$.